# Outlook - Copy group calendar events to user outlook calendar

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

We have a recurring event setup in Office 365 group calendar. If a new member is added to this group, that member can see the event in "Group" calendar and in order to see this event in main calendar, user have to click on "Copy to My calendar" in group event.

Is there any way to do this via code/script? Basically achieve "Copy to My calendar" for Office 365 group calendar to User's main calendar via code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when you click "Copy to my calendar" if it has some smart link or if it is just a copy at a point in time.

You could subscribe to the calendar using a webhook. That webhook would call your API hosted somewhere (an Azure Function, a web api hosted on Azure App Service). Your API would recieve the event id, it could then fetch the full details of the event and then create a new event on the users calendar.

I'm assuming that you'd want this to create it on all users calendar and also to update it if there were changes on the source event.

Its complex for sure doing it this way.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Hello Jeremy, problem here is this way it creates a new event, and there is no way to cascade updates from Group Calendar to User calendar. meaning, it would be possible to create new event, but in case of any updates to original event, it does not pass those changes to user calendar. As there is no property that ties both events.

Comment: Ah yes. I actually believe this should be an ask of the Group Calendar team on improving the Group calendar user experience in Outlook. I do hear this a lot and I wonder whether they maybe working on this.